# What is the name for this laser printer part, and is it user serviceable?

Tags: hardware-failure, laser-printer, hp-laserjet

What is the name of this printer part:

[image: part in respect to entire printer][image: close up of tear]

and is it user serviceable? The printer in question is a `HP Color LaserJet 2605dn`.

FYI: The rip started really small, but I needed to print stuff for school and it expanded, it didn't get that big through sheer stupidity.

--

**EDIT:**

Looks like $170 + S&H to fix, but the comparable printer (HP Color LaserJet CP2025dn) is $550 so it's a tough call. :-/

Comment: can you reupload your image with a freehand circle around what you're asking about, *specifically*? Your question is a little big vague.

Comment: @studiohack My original had a link to 2 images, a close-up and this context shot. I'll relink it for the question's rake

Comment: @ArtB Do think twice before deciding to repair this printer. There are known problems with toner dust accumulating on laser lens which can lead degradation of image quality and is difficult to clean (and as far as I know Hewlett-Packard is still ignoring the problem) and the collection of toner on the transfer belt is also a problem on some units.

Comment: @AndrejaKo Yeah but I don't see another networkable duplex printer that is even double the repair cost, and image quality is not that important to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ETB (Electrostatic Transfer Belt) has a tear in it. Fortunately, it is user-serviceable (cleanable and replaceable).

It is part # `RM1-1892-000CN` and will run around $150-$200. You can see instructions in the [service](http://www.partshere.com/models/q7823a/CLJ2605_removal_n_replacement.pdf) and [troubleshooting](http://www.partshere.com/Models/Q7823A/CLJ2605_troubleshooting.pdf) manuals.

For future reference, it’s not a good idea to put anything on it. Perhaps even avoid touching it since it is a critical part. `;-)`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know what to even Google for. It's looks like one of the rubber bands in it snapped and as we printed it put more pressure to where the band ended up bunching up.